# bound of random variable implies bound of conditional expectation?

Tags: probability

Given two *dependent* real random variables $X,Y$, suppose that

\begin{equation}
Y \leq c \Rightarrow X \leq k
\end{equation}
and that everything is well defined. I would like to argue that

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}[X \mid Y\leq c] \leq k 
\end{equation}

Does this upper bound hold?

$\textbf{Attempt}: $

consider $\mathcal{H} = \{ \omega \in \mathcal{F} \mid Y(\omega) \leq c \}$, where $\mathcal{F}$ is the sigma algebra of the corresponding probability space of $X$ and $Y$. By the previously defined implication we have:

\begin{equation}
X \mathbb{1}_{H} \leq k 
\end{equation}

for all $H\in \mathcal{H}$. By definition of conditional expectation we have

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X \mid Y\leq c] \mathbb{1}_{H}] = \mathbb{E}[X1_{H}] \leq k 
\end{equation}

Now i think that: Since $H$ was arbitrary and $\mathbb{E}[X \mid Y\leq c]$ is $\mathcal{H}$-measurable we conclude that

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}[X \mid Y\leq c] \leq k . 
\end{equation}

Any help would be very helpful.

Comment: Maybe I'm not fully understanding the subtleties, but if I have a real random variable which is restricted in range ($X\le$k), it seems like the expectation value should always be limited to the same range no matter what the distribution, so your bound certainly makes intuitive sense.  I hope this helps.

Comment: I’m not very familiar with probability theory or the notation so I don’t know whether your proof makes sense, but you’re essentially saying that you know $X \leq k$, and asking whether the expected value of $X$ is less than or equal to k, so I’m pretty sure the answer is yes

Comment: @Robo300 I don't know that $X \leq k$, I know that $Y \leq c \Rightarrow X \leq k$.

Comment: But your finding the expected value given $Y \leq c$, doesn’t that basically mean you can assume $Y \leq c$, which by the implication means you can assume $X \leq k$

Comment: @Robo300 This is exactly my question: the intuition is clear but does it also follow from the definition of conditional expectation?

Comment: You could say $\sum_{x} x\mathbb{P}[X|Y \leq c = x] = \sum_{x\leq k}k\mathbb{P}[X|Y \leq c = x] \leq k$, similarly for continuous distribution $X$

Comment: If I understand correctly, $Y\le c$ is an event so that $\mathbb E(X\mid Y\le c)$ is a real number. 

So we have, where $P$ denotes the probability measure and $\{Y\le c\}$ is shorthand for your $\mathcal H$, $$\mathbb E(X\mid Y\le c)=\frac1{P(\{Y\le c\})}\int_{\{Y\le c\}} X(\omega) \, \mathrm dP(\omega)\le \frac1{P(\{Y\le c\})}\int_{\{Y\le c\}} k \, \mathrm dP=k. $$